# Sum Column Totals from 2 tables

Tags: sql, select, join, sum

I am working on a SQL Query/View where I need to Sum the values of columns in each table.

So, I have the parent table: LIMIT
a Limit has many Allocations and many Extensions.
Each Allocation and each Extension has a source entity.

Both Allocation and Extension tables have columns: AR and MTM respectively.

I need to SUM AR and MTM in both Allocation and Extention tables into one column ARTotal and MTM Total. I need to do this for each SourceEntity. When I specify the Limit OID and the Source Entity OID I get the correct result for the given LIMIT and Source Entity. However I need to get all Source entites and all Limits Here is the code that returns the correct result for a specific Entity and Limit:

```
   SELECT MAX(la.SourceEntity) as Source,
   MAX(la.limit)as Limit,
   SUM(la.ARLimit) as LAARLimit,
   SUM(la.MTMLimit) as LAMTMLimit,

   MAX(la.SourceEntity) as Source,
   SUM(le.ARLimit) as LEARLimit,
   SUM(le.MTMLimit) as LEMTMLimit,

   (Sum(la.ARLimit) + SUM(le.ARLimit)) as ARLimitTotal

    FROM  LimitAllocation la 
    INNER JOIN LimitExtension le
    on la.Limit = le.Limit

    where la.Limit = le.Limit 
    and la.SourceEntity = 'XXXXXXXXXX-4D0C-460B-8E2C-1F32732A1A20'
    and la.Limit = 'XXXXXXXXX-19f1-4a0f-81db-9598c0f58ea7'
```

This result set return 1 record for the given Source Entity and Given Limit. And the values are correct.
[image: This is the correct result set ARTotal = LAAR + AEAR]

How do I get the results for Every Source Entity in the Allocation and Extention tables where they share the same LIMIT OID?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you mean.

Comment: Updated Query with Pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT la.SourceEntity as Source,
   MAX(la.limit)as Limit,
   SUM(la.ARLimit) as LAARLimit,
   SUM(la.MTMLimit) as LAMTMLimit,

   la.SourceEntity as Source,
   SUM(le.ARLimit) as LEARLimit,
   SUM(le.MTMLimit) as LEMTMLimit,

   (Sum(la.ARLimit) + SUM(le.ARLimit)) as ARLimitTotal

    FROM  LimitAllocation la 
    INNER JOIN LimitExtension le
    on la.Limit = le.Limit

    where la.Limit = le.Limit 
   -- and la.SourceEntity = 'XXXXXXXXXX-4D0C-460B-8E2C-1F32732A1A20'
   -- and la.Limit = 'XXXXXXXXX-19f1-4a0f-81db-9598c0f58ea7'

GROUP BY la.SourceEntity
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing group by.